# How can I extract all text from XML data using PHP (i.e. SimpleXmlElement)?

Tags: php, xml

Here's my XML data:

```
$data = '<title>Report of the <org reg="International Foo and Bar Conference, 5th">Fifth International Foo and Bar Conference</org>, <org>Foobar Hall</org>, London, July 14 to 16, 1908.</title>';
```

I can load it:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $data ); 
print_r( $xml );
```

This returns:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [org] => Array (
        [0] => Fifth International Foo and Bar Conference
        [1] => Foobar Hall ) )
```

But now I can try to get it in a string again:

```
$flat = (string) $xml;
print_r( $flat );
```

And this is what I see:

```
Report of the , , London, July 14 to 16, 1908.
```

But I'd rather it was this:

```
Report of the Fifth International Foo and Bar Conference, Foobar Hall, London, July 14 to 16, 1908.
```

Is there an easy way to do that with PHP, without explicitly recursing through every node? That's to say, is there a way to just flatten the XML and extract all the text from it, regardless of tags?

Comment: Have you considered a regex to remove all tags from your original string ?

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily done in DOM. DOM element nodes have a property $textContent, that will return its text content including all descendant text nodes.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($data);
var_dump($document->documentElement->textContent);
```

Output:

```
string(99) "Report of the Fifth International Foo and Bar Conference, Foobar Hall, London, July 14 to 16, 1908."
```

If you do not have the element node already in a variable, it will be more convenient to use XPath.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($data);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(/title)'));
```

It is even possible to convert a `SimpleXMLElement` into a DOM element node.

```
$element = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$node = dom_import_simplexml($element);
var_dump($node->textContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

the docs for `__toString` on SimpleXMLElement says: "Returns text content that is directly in this element. Does not return text content that is inside this element's children."

The `asXML` method seems to be better for what you want: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php

it will return a string:

`"<?xml version="1.0"?>
<title>Report of the <org reg="International Foo and Bar Conference, 5th">Fifth International Foo and Bar Conference</org>, <org>Foobar Hall</org>, London, July 14 to 16, 1908.</title>
"`

https://eval.in/410230

You'd have to strip out the opening XML tag though, but it's much better.