# PHP and XML: get full node content

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML like:

```
<elements version="1.0">
    <files>
        <file id="125173909582">
            <text>aaa</text>
            <source>eee</source>
            <tag>InterInChina</tag>
        </file>
    </files>
</elements>
```

I need to get (as a string) the content of each node, but as it is!
For example, frm the xml above, i need to output a string like: 
aaaeeeInterInChina 
for each "file" node.

I am now in this situation:

```
$request_url="http://www.example.com";
$xml=simplexml_load_file($request_url);
foreach($xml->posts->children() as $file) {
    $id=$file["id"];
    $content=$file->asXML();
}
```

but the $content is not what i need because it's all the node with the  also.

Thanks to you all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I extract all text from XML data using PHP (i.e. SimpleXmlElement)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766136/how-can-i-extract-all-text-from-xml-data-using-php-i-e-simplexmlelement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont want the xml. You want to itterate trough your files. and itterate trough the variables after. You can itterate with foreach:

lets start with setting up your xml like you ahve it with multiple files:

```
    $content='<elements version="1.0">
    <files>
        <file id="125173909582">
            <text>aaa</text>
            <source>eee</source>
            <tag>InterInChina</tag>
        </file>

        <file id="125173909582">
            <text>bb</text>
            <source>sss</source>
            <tag>bla</tag>
        </file>
    </files>
</elements>';


    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
```

now we can itterate it like this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
foreach($xml->files->file as $file){
echo "<h1>file</h1>"; 
    foreach($file as $key=>$value){
        if(!is_array($value)){
            echo $key . " = ".$value."<br>"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i know what i want.
but your code it's ok... with my edit: echo "<".$key.">".$value."</".$key.">"

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this;

```
$data = '<elements version="1.0">
    <files>
        <file id="125173909582">
            <text>aaa</text>
            <source>eee</source>
            <tag>InterInChina</tag>
        </file>
    </files>
</elements>';
//$request_url="http://www.example.com";
//$xml=simplexml_load_file($request_url);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);//for test

foreach($xml->files as $k=>$data){
    resp = $data->file->text.' '.$data->file->source.' '.$data->file->tag;  
}
var_dump($resp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @mark_smit it's ok... but the right answer of my question is:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
foreach($xml->files->file as $file){
    foreach($file as $key=>$value){
        if(!is_array($value)){
            echo "<".$key.">".$value."</".$key.">"; 
        }
    }
}
```