# Convert XML into flat array. Working but just a little XPath hint

Tags: php, arrays, xml

This is an excerpt of a huge XML exported from a dB of italian laws. I would like to convert it to a flat array. (The goal is to extract and convert part of this XML into a RTF document and I find easier to manipulate it using regex).

```
$xml_string = <<<XML    
<CodiceRegionale>
    <sommario>
        <elementoCapitolo>CAP a1</elementoCapitolo>
        <elementoCapitoloDescr>
        </elementoCapitoloDescr>
        <elementoSommarioLegge>
             <elementoTesto>1.1 Legge</elementoTesto>
        </elementoSommarioLegge>
    </sommario>
    <LeggeRegionale id="urn:nir:2014-12-12;26" xmlns="http://www.normeinrete.it/nir/2.1/">
         <elementoSommario xmlns="">
             <elementoCapitolo>CAP a1</elementoCapitolo>
             <elementoCapitoloDescr>
             </elementoCapitoloDescr>
             <elementoSettore />
             <elementoSettoreDescr />
         </elementoSommario>
         <intestazione>Lex 12 2014, n. 26.</intestazione>
             <articolato>
                 <articolo id="art41" xmlns="http://www.normeinrete.it/nir/2.1/">
                     <num>Art. 41</num>
                     <rubrica>(Riforma della finanza locale)</rubrica>
                     <comma id="art41-com1">
                          <num>1. </num>
                          <alinea>Al fine di supportare...</alinea>
                          <el id="art41-com1-let_a">
                              <num>a) </num>
                              <corpo>definizione di...</corpo>
                          </el>
                          <el id="art41-com1-let_b">
                               <num>b) </num>
                               <corpo>coordinamento della...</corpo>
                           </el>
                           <el id="art41-com1-let_c">
                               <num>c) </num>
                               <corpo>definizione delle...</corpo>
                           </el>
                           <el id="art41-com1-let_d">
                               <num>d) </num>
                               <corpo>la disciplina...</corpo>
                           </el>
                      </comma>
                      <comma id="art41-com2">
                           <num>2. </num>
                           <alinea>La revisione di...</alinea>
                           <el id="art41-com2-let_a">
                               <num>a) </num>
                               <corpo>
                                    razionalizzazione e...
                                    <rif xlink:href="urn:nir:stato:legge:2010-12-13;220#art1-com154" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">articolo 1, comma 154, della legge 13 dicembre 2010, n. 220</rif>
                                    (Legge di stabilità 2011);
                               </corpo>
                           </el>
                           <el id="art41-com2-let_b">
                               <num>b) </num>
                               <corpo>
                                    applicazione dei...
                                    <rif xlink:href="urn:nir:stato:costituzione:1947-12-27#art119" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">articolo 119 della Costituzione</rif>
                                    , nonché del principio...
                               </corpo>
                           </el>
                           <el id="art41-com2-let_c">
                               <num>c) </num>
                               <corpo>valorizzazione...</corpo>
                           </el>
                           <el id="art41-com2-let_d">
                               <num>d) </num>
                               <corpo>previsione di...</corpo>
                           </el>
                           <el id="art41-com2-let_e">
                               <num>e) </num>
                               <corpo>valorizzazione del...</corpo>
                           </el>
                           <el id="art41-com2-let_f">
                               <num>f) </num>
                               <corpo>previsione di...</corpo>
                           </el>
                       </comma>
                       <comma id="art41-com3">
                           <num>3. </num>
                           <corpo>La revisione normativa...</corpo>
                       </comma>
                       <comma id="art41-com4">
                           <num>4. </num>
                           <corpo>I disegni di...</corpo>
                       </comma>
                  </articolo>
                  <articolo id="art42" xmlns="http://www.normeinrete.it/nir/2.1/">
                      <num>Art. 42</num>
                      <rubrica>(Supporto finanziario regionale agli enti locali)</rubrica>
                      <comma id="art42-com1">
                          <num>1. </num>
                          <corpo>Il supporto...</corpo>
                      </comma>
                      <comma id="art42-com2">
                          <num>2. </num>
                          <corpo>Per le finalità di...</corpo>
                      </comma>
                      <comma id="art42-com3">
                          <num>3. </num>
                          <corpo>Gli incentivi regionali...</corpo>
                      </comma>
                      <comma id="art42-com4">
                          <num>4. </num>
                          <corpo>
                                In attuazione...
                                <rif xlink:href="urn:nir:stato:decreto.legislativo:1997-01-02;9#art9" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">articolo 9 ...</rif>
                                (Norme di attuazione dello
                                <rif xlink:href="urn:nir:regione.friuli.venezia.giulia:statuto:" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">statuto</rif>
                                speciale...
                          </corpo>
                      </comma>
                      <comma id="art42-com5">
                          <num>5. </num>
                          <corpo>Le modalità...</corpo>
                      </comma>
                  </articolo>
             </articolato>
        </LeggeRegionale>
        <LeggeRegionale id="urn:nir:2015-05-22;12" xmlns="http://www.normeinrete.it/nir/2.1/">
            <elementoSommario xmlns="">
                <elementoCapitolo>CAP a7</elementoCapitolo>
                <elementoCapitoloDescr>
                </elementoCapitoloDescr>
                <elementoSettore />
                <elementoSettoreDescr />
            </elementoSommario>
            <intestazione>Lex 22 2015 n. 12...</intestazione>
            <articolato>
                <articolo id="art6">
                    <num>Art. 6</num>
                    <rubrica>(Regolamento interno del CAL)</rubrica>
                    <comma id="art6-com1">
                        <num>1. </num>
                        <corpo>Il CAL approva...</corpo>
                    </comma>
                    <comma id="art6-com2">
                        <num>2. </num>
                        <alinea>Il regolamento...</alinea>
                        <el id="art6-com2-let_a">
                            <num>a) </num>
                            <corpo>l'elezione...</corpo>
                        </el>
                        <el id="art6-com2-let_b">
                            <num>b) </num>
                            <corpo>le funzioni degli organi del CAL;</corpo>
                        </el>
                        <el id="art6-com2-let_c">
                            <num>c) </num>
                            <corpo>la costituzione...</corpo>
                        </el>
                        <el id="art6-com2-let_d">
                            <num>d) </num>
                            <corpo>la programmazione...</corpo>
                        </el>
                        <el id="art6-com2-let_e">
                            <num>e) </num>
                            <corpo>i casi nei...</corpo>
                        </el>
                        <el id="art6-com2-let_f">
                            <num>f) </num>
                            <corpo>le modalità di...</corpo>
                        </el>
                    </comma>
                    <comma id="art6-com3">
                        <num>3. </num>
                        <corpo>Il regolamento è pubblicato...</corpo>
                    </comma>
               </articolo>
          </articolato>
     </LeggeRegionale>
     <LeggeRegionale id="urn:nir:2014-12-12;26" xmlns="http://www.normeinrete.it/nir/2.1/">
         <elementoSommario xmlns="">
             <elementoCapitolo>CAP a8</elementoCapitolo>
             <elementoCapitoloDescr>
             </elementoCapitoloDescr>
             <elementoSettore />
             <elementoSettoreDescr />
         </elementoSommario>
         <intestazione>Lex 12 2014, n. 26....</intestazione>
         <articolato>
             <articolo id="art17">
                  <num>Art. 17</num>
                  <rubrica>(Piano dell'Unione)</rubrica>
                  <comma id="art17-com1">
                      <num>1. </num>
                      <corpo>Il Piano dell'Unione...</corpo>
                  </comma>
                  <comma id="art17-com2">
                      <num>2. </num>
                      <corpo>
                                            Il Piano ...
                                            <rif xlink:href="urn:nir:stato:decreto.legislativo:2000;267#art170" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">articolo 170 ...</rif>
                                            .
                      </corpo>
                 </comma>
                 <comma id="art17-com3">
                     <num>3. </num>
                     <corpo>Il Piano dell'Unione...</corpo>
                 </comma>
                 <comma id="art17-com4">
                     <num>4. </num>
                     <corpo>La relazione annuale...</corpo>
                 </comma>
            </articolo>
        </articolato>
   </LeggeRegionale>
   <LeggeRegionale id="urn:nir:regione.friuli.venezia.giulia:legge:2014-12-12;26" xmlns="http://www.normeinrete.it/nir/2.1/">
       <elementoSommario xmlns="">
           <elementoCapitolo>CAP a14</elementoCapitolo>
           <elementoCapitoloDescr>
           </elementoCapitoloDescr>
           <elementoSettore />
           <elementoSettoreDescr />
       </elementoSommario>
       <intestazione>Lex 12 dicembre 2014, n. 26 ....</intestazione>
       <articolato>
           <articolo id="art5">
               <num>Art. 5</num>
               <rubrica>(Unioni territoriali intercomunali)</rubrica>
               <comma id="art5-com1">
                   <num>1. </num>
                   <corpo>Le Unioni territoriali...</corpo>
               </comma>
               <comma id="art5-com2">
                   <num>2. </num>
                   <corpo>
                                L'Unione ha...
                                <rif xlink:href="urn:nir:stato:decreto.legislativo:2000-08-18;267#art32" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">articolo 32...</rif>
                                (Testo unico delle leggi sull'ordinamento degli enti locali).
                   </corpo>
              </comma>
         </articolo>
    </articolato>
</LeggeRegionale>
</CodiceRegionale>
XML;
```

To convert it to a flat array, I'm using [Yoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533790/xml-into-associative-array-using-php) solution which is what I was looking for:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml_string);    
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$result = array();

foreach ($xpath->query('//*[count(*) = 0]') as $node) {
    $path = array();
    $val = $node->nodeValue;
    do {
        if ($node->hasAttributes()) {
            foreach ($node->attributes as $attribute) {
                $path[] = sprintf('%s[%s]', $attribute->nodeName, $attribute->nodeValue);
            }
        }
        $path[] = $node->nodeName;
    }
    while ($node = $node->parentNode);
    $result[implode('/', array_reverse($path))] = $val;
}

print_r($result);
```

Unfortunately the above script **doesn't get the values between the tag `corpo` when there's a tag `rif` inside**:

```
<corpo>
    razionalizzazione e...
    <rif xlink:href="urn:nir:stato:legge:2010-12-13;220#art1-com154" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">articolo 1, comma 154, della legge 13 dicembre 2010, n. 220</rif>
   (Legge di stabilità 2011);
</corpo>
```

**It does get** the value inside the `<rif>` tag, but **it does not get** the values *razionalizzazione e...* and *(Legge di stabilità 2011);*

Expected output should be:

```
[#document/CodiceRegionale/LeggeRegionale/id[urn:nir:2014-12-12;26]/articolato/articolo/id[art41]/comma/id[art41-com2]/el/id[art41-com2-let_a]/corpo] => razionalizzazione e... articolo 1, comma 154, della legge 13 dicembre 2010, n. 220 (Legge di stabilità 2011);
```

As I'm really new to XML, kindly show me how to fix the above script.

Comment: That is not bad XML, the problem is the SimpleXML API. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31766803/2265374

Comment: Thank you for point me out that: I tried your solution without success because I don't have knowledge about SimpleXML. I edited my question explaining the output expected. I'm pretty sure that the script I'm using above needs only a very little change to work as wished but I really don't know what should be edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to make an exception to your script's rule of capturing any element without child elements (`//*[count(*) = 0]`) when you encounter `<corpo>` elements(?). To do that:

Replace:

```
$xpath->query('//*[count(*) = 0]')
```

With:

```
$xpath->query('//*[(count(*) = 0 or name() = "corpo") and name() != "rif"]')
```

This will take the text value of any `<corpo>` elements and ignore `<rif>` elements. Although the solution is quite brittle by hard coding corpo and rif handling logic.

Note, as an aside, I would favor learning [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) to parse something that is already XML over parsing to something suitable for regexp, as a general approach.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer solves the problem posted so I award the 50 points. Unfortunately I got stuck again as soon I parsed the XML using your solution. The XML I'm working on has much more levels than those shown in the excerpt above: sometimes it uses a certain tag, sometimes it uses an other tag for describing the same thing. I'm pretty tired about. I think I'm going to give up.

Comment: Np. I'm not exactly sure what problem your tackling but I would suggest taking the time to learn XPath. It was designed specifically for querying XML documents. XSLT is also something that I would consider for transforming XML into some other type of document (even RTF) in the long run.