# PHP SimpleXMLElement: can I get innertext with saveXML(), or outerHTML with (string)?

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I have an application where the user writes XPath queries to use as source data from a given document. Sometimes they need just the contents of an element, sometimes they need the whole element itself. To my understanding they should be able to specify either text() or node() at the end of their query to choose which behavior.

But it seems like the way I get a string out of the SimpleXMLElement determines the behavior, regardless of the query.

When I cast the query to (string), it ALWAYS only returns inner XML.

```
(string) $xml->xpath('//document/head/Keywords')[0] === 
(string) $xml->xpath('//document/head/Keywords/node()')[0] === 
(string) $xml->xpath('//document/head/Keywords/text()')[0] === 
'17';
```

If I use ->saveXML(), it ALWAYS returns the entire tag.

```
$xml->xpath('//document/head/Keywords')[0]->asXML() === 
$xml->xpath('//document/head/Keywords/node()')[0]->asXML() === 
$xml->xpath('//document/head/Keywords/text()')[0]->asXML() === 
'<Keywords topic="611x27keqj">17</Keywords>';
```

Is there a single way that I can get a string, which allows my users to specify inner vs outer XML as a part of their XPath query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I extract all text from XML data using PHP (i.e. SimpleXmlElement)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766136/how-can-i-extract-all-text-from-xml-data-using-php-i-e-simplexmlelement)

Answer (score 0):

The SimpleXML `xpath()` method always returns `SimpleXMLElement` objects representing either an element or an attribute, never text. The methods you show in the question are the correct way to use that object to get text content or full XML.

If you want richer (but less simple) XPath functionality, you will have to use [the DOM](http://php.net/dom), and specifically [the DOMXPath class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). Note that you can freely mix SimpleXML and DOM using [simplexml_import_dom](http://php.net/simplexml_import_dom) and [dom_import_simplexml](http://php.net/dom_import_simplexml); the internal representation is the same, so you can switch between the two "wrappers" with minimal cost.